# Why can't I create soft link on vboxsf file system?

Tags: virtualbox

`ln -s` keeps saying me that file system is read-only, however it is not.

```
ice@distantstar:~/virt 
➜ touch file
ice@distantstar:~/virt 
➜ rm file
ice@distantstar:~/virt 
➜ ln -s ~/.bashrc ~/virt/.bashrc
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/home/ice/virt/.bashrc': Read-only file system
ice@distantstar:~/virt 
➜ mount | grep virt
none on /home/ice/virt type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime)
ice@distantstar:~/virt 
➜ cat /etc/fstab | grep virt
VIRT    /home/ice/virt  vboxsf rw   0   0
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Virtual Box 4.1.8, creating symlinks using a guest-OS in a shared folder has been disabled for security reasons.

For more information, check out this ticket:
[VirtualBox Ticket 10085 Disabled Symlinks](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085)
To re enable, you can try running this command:

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME 1
```

where `SHARE_NAME` is the name of your Shared Folder.

Alternatively you can downgrade to 4.1.6 and that should fix the issue.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Now I have `ln: failed to create symbolic link \`/home/ice/virt/.bashrc': Protocol error`

Comment: Well, my bad. I was trying to create link to file in the guest OS's filesystem. which makes no sense, obviously. Vice versa it works: `ln -s ~/virt/file ~`

Comment: Very good solution, but this is reported to not to work anymore in recent 4.2 releases. Whenever I'm creating a symbolic link on a shared folder (independent of the destitnation) I get `ln: failed to create symbolic link 'linkname': Protocol error` It's just sad this hasn't been addressed properly. Any new work around verified to work in 4.2.6+?

Comment: @gertvdijk if you're running a Windows host, you may want to run VirtualBox as administrator, it needs special privileges to be able to create Windows-style symlinks.

Comment: Don't forget once you have run this command to restart your virtual box machine

Comment: This does not work on Virtual box 5

Comment: Worked for me on Virtualbox 5.2. Needed to run VB as admin though.

Comment: where should I run this command. I'm on windows 10. shall I run this command using powershell?

Comment: Didn't worked for me using VirtualBox 5.2.8 on Windows 7 running a Debian Stretch, running VB as Admin, having restarted VB entirely